# cron - how to automatically invoke/start an Android App in the Emulator at specific time?

Tags: android, android-emulator, cron

here's the problem:
I installed an App on the Android Emulator, and I want to invoke/start the app at some specific time. Is there any easy way (like a cron job or something similar) to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is what is called AlarmManager, you can read more about it at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @Waqas  lots of people are mentioning this. But I am not the developer of the App. Any way to run it like a cron job?